# QSBS for restricted stock options

Tags: united-states, taxes, employee-stock-options, start-up

The below applies to a US company

I have started at a company where I have received stock that has a 1 year cliff and a 4 year vesting schedule. I earlier exercised my stock and filled out a 83b form. Two months after I started, the company will raise money valuing the company over 50M.

Timeline:

- t0: early exercise shares that are unvested (FMV of company is 20M)
- t1 (3 months from t0): company raises money at 100M
- t2 (12 months from t0): 1/4 of stock vests

The first question, will the QSBS tax reduction apply to all the stock I early exercised despite the fact it was not yet vested? If not, will the reduction apply to the stock when it vests? It is unclear if the " issuance of such stock" applies to when I early exercied or when the stock will vest.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.qsbsexpert.com/83b-elections-and-qsbs/, all your shares will qualify for QSBS as long as you meet all the other conditions:

> According to the Code of Federal Regulations and its [subchapter on
> income tax](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.83-4),
>
> > “Under section 83(f), the holding period of transferred property to
> > which section 83(a) applies shall begin just after such property is
> > substantially vested. However, if the person who has performed the
> > services in connection with which property is transferred has made an
> > election under section 83(b), the holding period of such property
> > shall begin just after the date such property is transferred.”
>
> We determine this to mean that if the shares issued to an individual
> by the corporation meet all necessary conditions in Section 1202, and
> if the shareholder files an 83(b) election in a timely manner, then
> the 5 year holding period begins on the date the restricted shares
> were issued.

They reference restricted stock units, but I have no reason to think it would be different with stock options.